# can't persist jpa entity in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

```
   @Entity
   public class Blobx {

        private String name;
        private BlobKey blobKey;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Key id;

        //getters and setters 
     }
@Entity
public class Userx  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Blobx> blobs;
    //getters and setters 
}
```

while persiting the above Userx entity object i am encountering

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Field "entities.Userx.blobs" contains a persistable object that isnt persistent, but the field doesnt allow cascade-persist!
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need to add a `cascade` attribute so that the JPA provider can cascade persist on the new `Blobx` added to the `blobs`. Currently, the JPA provider can't, as reported by the error message. So change it like this (adapt the `CascadeType` to match your needs):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
private List<Blobx> blobs;
```